# Add active-class to carousel-item when form-option is selected

Tags: html, slider, carousel, html-select

I'm building up a configurator for a friend and I need help for the very last step: When I select an option in my form, the class "active" needs to be placed on a specific carousel-item.

The form-selections must be used, there is no other option for it.

Here is the link to the little page:
https://abaci2.hirschgeweyh.de/

It's a shirt where you can switch to the options. "manschetten" is the one I need first, so I can later copy the JavaScript/HTML.

I already tried addclass/removeclass but it didn't help, even the change-query couldn't handle it. It looks like there is no solution to tell the page which option has been selected right now to put in the class.

Here is a typical selection:

```
<tr class="auswahl0205" id="auswahl0205">
    <td><strong>Manschetten</strong></td>
    <td><select name="manschetten">
  <option class="manschette1" data-class="manschette1" value="manschette1">Einzelmanschette</option>
  <option class="manschette2" data-class="manschette2" value="manschette2">Doppelmanschette</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
```

And here is the carousel-slider in which I need the active-class:

```
<div id="slider04" class="manschetten carousel carousel1 slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item mansch mansch1 active"><img src="assets/img/manschetten/manschette1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="img1"></div>
<div class="carousel-item mansch mansch2"><img src="assets/img/manschetten/manschette2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="img2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't get any kind of proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured out that the select-element can get an "active" class and in the theory used as the carousel-indicator. But that doesn't work for unknown reasons (maybe because I don't really click on the new indicator but "switch" the label instead). Long story short: it won't work - maybe someone else will find a solution.

So what I did was quite simple: instead of using select options I used ul li and made them navigate the images with the bootstrap carousel:

```
        <td>
        <ul class="">
            <li data-target="#slider04" data-slide-to="0" class="active">Einzelmanschette</li>
            <li data-target="#slider04" data-slide-to="1">Doppelmanschette</li>
        </ul>
        </td>
```

It worked like charm!

And to make it look like a select, I used just CSS. Done! Case closed!